# progressive http download to a file

Tags: download

I want to redirect the output of the command "wget" to a file, but i do not want to fill the file at the end of the command, but I want to fill it progressively. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the file is not filled progressively but it is only filled at the end of the command.

Comment: No it doesn't. Try `tail -f file.html` from other terminal and yo'll see

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -qO- www.stackoverflow.com > file.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `curl` with the `--no-buffer` flag.